# How to check which table has the ID and query its row

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a few tables with exact same schema, the only reason its separate is because they are huge. 
So if i do a

```
select * from 
(select * from ptable p1
union select * from ptable2 p2
.. and so on) pp
where pid=1234
```

, it will take really long time.

I like to write a one where i check ptable(s) for pid value of 1234, if it exist, then select the row from the right table.
How do i do that? pid is unique and will only exist in one table, it is also not in any sorted order.

Comment: Also post a table structure with `SHOW CREATE TABLE [your_table_name]` and `EXPLAIN [your_query]`

Answer (score 1):

I manage to solve my problem after some experiment, not sure if its the best way being an amateur but it works.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 'sproc'(IN pQryID INT)
BEGIN

select count(*) as count into @rowCountp1 from p1 where pid=pQryID;
select count(*) as count into @rowCountp2 from p2 where pid=pQryID;
.. and so on for other similar tables ..

if @rowCountp1>0 THEN
(SELECT * from p1 where pid=pQryID);
elseif @rowCountp2>0 THEN
(SELECT ( from p2 where pid=pQryID);
end if;

END
```